# Spreadsheet uploading appropriate for business/end-users in Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

Does Foundry have native support for uploading and appending spreadsheets (identical schema) to one dataset, with an interface appropriate for business/end-users?

I'm evaluating a user workflow that involves receiving tabular spreadsheets ad-hoc and appending them using regular programmatic methods. I'm trying to enable this workflow in Foundry, wherein users would upload these spreadsheets (identical schema) to a single dataset in Foundry, integrated into downstream pipelines. The workflow would look like this:

> 1. User navigates to spreadsheet upload page
> 2. Button for import or upload
> 3. Hit button, enables selection of spreadsheet to upload
> 4. Upload
> 5. File is appended to the dataset

OPTIONAL: Users have the ability to delete uploaded spreadsheets from the dataset.

I'm aware that users can upload multiple CSV / Excel files to a single dataset via APPEND options, but the interface is not suitable for end-users, i.e. it's possible to overwrite (SNAPSHOT) the entire dataset if the wrong option is selected. A prior discussion was raised here but never resolved: [How to import excel/csv with "File Import" widget in Foundry's Slate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555988/how-to-import-excel-csv-with-file-import-widget-in-foundrys-slate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of robust approaches to enable this workflow. Foundry Actions combined with Workshop present a robust option to enable ad-hoc uploads and appends of spreadsheets (or any file formats) to a specific dataset, with an interface appropriate for business/end-users.

Actions can be configured to support Attachment uploads - these are easily configurable, enable add/delete of specific files, and support uploads of single files up to 200MB. A Workshop app can be created to support a workflow where the user uploads the files to a dataset via Action. Then, uploaded files can be called down via API calls to the attachment RID, parsed and appended to the dataset in a transform.

- Actions: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/overview/
- Workshop: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/overview/
- API calls to attachment:
  https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/ontology-resources/attachments/get-attachment-content/

Comment: can you share any sample code of this @l99
I am interested in understanding how this works